# How to connect your private APIs to Watson assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, business-intelligence

I am building a Business Intelligent chat bot where data is retrieved from APIs. I am making the API calls from cloud functions filtering and returning the data.

I can make calls while I am connected to VPN but not from outside (IBM cloud functions)

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
def reports(api_url):
    r = requests.get(url)['Body']
    df = pd.read_json(r)
    #filtered report
    filtered_df = df[df['state']=='CA']
    return filtered_df.to_json()
```

The above api_url is private. I get HTTP connection error when called IBM cloud functions.

Comment: Not enough to go on for root cause. Why not use the `ibm_watson` module to get the data? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Comment: Seems to be a normal network related restriction. ie. nothing in the cloud is able to see your private APIs because their routing tables / DNS addressing does not include your private address.

Comment: Network restricted APIs. Using orchestration layer to manage the internal data. This does not allow me to use watson assistant dialogue capabilities to full extent.